# What caption is best for a detail form?

Tags: data

Think of a grid: you double-click the row to open a detail form for an existing 'xxx' - what is the best caption to use for consistency across an application.

These all appear in my app currently but I want to be more consistent and use one.
 - "Edit xxx"
 - "Open xxx"
 - "Modify xxx"

(Yes, this is subjective but doesn't require discussion)

Comment: By caption do you mean the title of the page when you get to it?

Comment: I did but now I think about it, I prefer to use the same caption for the buttons & context menus that will open it too. 
The detail form is typically a modal form (WinForms app) and there isn't always something that identifies it - e.g. the Product Name in your example. Mine would be something general like "Edit Complaint" with the context supplied by the focused grid row.
That probably rules out "Open xxx" which works well on a context menu but not on the detail form whereas "Modify Complaint" or "Edit Complaint" pair together ok.

Answer (score 1):

### Viewing

If you are just viewing (read only) then you could just use the name of it as the title e.g. - **xxx**

Or if you want to specifiy the type of item too then - **Type: xxx** e.g. ***Product: Product Name***

---

### Editing

If you are in edit mode then you could emphasise that to make it clear to the user that they are in edit mode and use - **Editing - xxx** or **Editing - Type: xxx**

Answer (score 0):

Check out how others do what you're doing. It's usually best to use the conventions that people already know.

So, if I understand your question, I agree with Dave: make the name of the thing a link to open it.

Now you just need an "Edit" button. The connection between the button and the thing might be so obvious that you only need to label the button "Edit." Or use one of those pencil icons. If it's less obvious what "Edit" refers to, then add the item label to it: "Edit xxx."

Or leave "Edit" off of your grid and move it to the detail page you get to by clicking the name.